# How to extract filtered data from Datatables jQuery plugin?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-plugins, datatables

I am using the jQuery plugin [Datatables](http://www.datatables.net) for sorting, filtering, paginating large amounts of data from a MySQL database using PHP.  I need my application to run particular functions based on the filtered data in the table.

An example would be that one of my Datatables displays all of the users in the system, which can be filtered by user type (limited, standard, admin).  I'd like to be able to run a function to print detailed records for the filtered users.

Does the Datatables plugin allow me to do this?  If so, I haven't found anything in the documentation that is intuitive.

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

What you want is `fnGetFilteredNodes`, from API plug-in.

Check [the documentation here](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api).

I think you should have a hidden column to store the record IDs, and then loop the results of `fnGetFilteredNodes` to get the filtered IDs, to finally perform the task you want (like having the details of the filtered users from server-side...)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dataTables.fnGetFilteredNodes.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();

        $('#button').click( function () {
            var nFiltered = oTable.fnGetFilteredNodes();
            // do something with the results
            alert( nFiltered.length +' nodes were returned' );
        } );
    } );
</script>
```

Comment: Interesting.  I didn't see this sort of option before.  So I guess I could store the record IDs into an array, and then run my function based on those values?

Comment: ._('tr', {"filter":"applied"})